# WTL app wizard and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, wtl

With Visual Studio 2013, when I select the ATL/WTL Application Wizard, entering a project name and clicking OK, I remain on the first page of the wizard.  No new project is created and no error message is generated.

Is there a bug in the template code when WTL is used with 2013 or a problem with my configuration?

Comment: I'm sure whoever downvoted this question did so for some other reason than he personally doesn't know the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by downloading WTL 9 and running setup.js script found in the setup directory.  It re-installed the WTL template to all of my instances of Visual Studio and now the wizard works.  I'm not sure it installs correctly if it's downloaded via the Online service.